# can't take address of function unless createing delegate instance

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, pass-by-reference

I have a class defined as below:

```
ref class myClass
{
    PictureBox^ pic2;
public:
    void setPic2() { pic2 = gcnew PictureBox; }

    template<typename UnaryOperator>
    void setPic2Click(Form^ x, UnaryOperator op) { pic2->Click += gcnew EventHandler(x, op); }
};
```

And in my Windows form class:

```
namespace testProject 
{
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        void Form1_Load(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
        {
            rect1.setPic2(); 
            rect1.setPic2Click(this, std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Form1::pic2_Click), this));
        }

        void pic2_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
        {
            // do something...
        }
```

When compiled, it generated this error which is related to the `rect1.setPic2Click` call...:

> error C3374: can't take address of `'testProject::Form1::pic2_Click'` unless creating delegate instance

Basically, I tried to encapsulate the interface of the picturebox by create the instance method `setPic2Click`. Is this the right approach? Any suggestion how to remedy this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is that you're trying to mix managed and unmanaged C++/CLI code in a way that doesn't work (and doesn't make sense).

.NET delegates already have a bound first parameter.  All you need is:

```
class1->setPic2Click(gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::pic2_Click));
```

and

```
void setPic2Click(System::EventHandler^ op) {pic2->Click += op;}
```